# Duplicated variable with PHP POST for shopping cart inside double folder

Tags: php, post

I'd appreciate some help to fix the following issue.

I'm implementing the shopping cart of this [place](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/06/creating-simple-shopping-cart-with-php)

What happens is that when I click "add" button it shows the shopping cart and the list of products, but when I hit add again I see the POST places the variable again in the url so it can't find the php file and throws the Not Found error.

**Summary:**
When I click the first time on "add" button it shows website.com/folder1/folder2/store.php and when I click a second time it shows. website.com/folder1/folder2/**folder2**/cart_update.php (folder 2 is repeated)

**What I've tried:**
I tried to do unset but seems it is not working for me.

This shopping cart resides inside a double directory and I've been trying to tell the server it is inside a double folder but I can't make it work.

So shopping cart is live like this. http://website.com/folder1/folder2/store.php

I have renamed the index.php to store.php

I've tried to change the variable $current_url by adding the ./folder2 option but it doesn't work. It is like it is not being detected. I'm not sure what is happening.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
//current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
$current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
<h1 align="center">Products </h1>
<link href="http://website.com/folder1/folder2/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- View Cart Box Start -->
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_products"])>0)
{
    echo '<div class="cart-view-table-front" id="view-cart">';
    echo '<h3>Your Shopping Cart</h3>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
    echo '<table width="100%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">';
    echo '<tbody>';

    $total =0;
    $b = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
        $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
        $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
        $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
        $product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
        $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; //zebra stripe
        echo '<tr class="'.$bg_color.'">';
        echo '<td>Qty <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /> Remove</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
        $total = ($total + $subtotal);
    }
    echo '<td colspan="4">';
    echo '<button type="submit">Update</button><a href="view_cart.php" class="button">Checkout</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';

    $current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';

}
?>
<!-- View Cart Box End -->


<!-- Products List Start -->
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
if($results){ 
$products_item = '<ul class="products">';
//fetch results set as object and output HTML

while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item .= <<<EOT
    <li class="product">
    <form method="post" action="folder2/cart_update.php">
    <div class="product-content"><h3>{$obj->product_name}</h3>
    <div class="product-thumb"><img src="http://website.com/folder1/folder2/images/{$obj->product_img_name}"></div>
    <div class="product-desc">{$obj->product_desc}</div>
    <div class="product-info">
    Price {$currency}{$obj->price} 

    <fieldset>

    <!--<label>
        <span>Color</span>
        <select name="product_color">
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
        </select>
    </label>-->

    <label>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
    </label>

    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
    <div align="center"><button type="submit" class="add_to_cart">Add</button></div>
    </div></div>
    </form>
    </li>
EOT;
}
$products_item .= '</ul>';
echo $products_item;
}
?>    
<!-- Products List End -->
```

Comment: Take a look at RFC 2396, start at section 5 (page 15) and read page 16 as well.  See if you can figure out what's going on: http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2396.txt

Comment: Try `/folder1/folder2/cart_update.php` in your form action.

Comment: Hey @ymas, the document was helpful. I used the full url and the problem now is solved. Thanks